# need to set inputs disable when a value is selected from select input

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I need to set these three inputs disable

```
<input type="text" class="col-md-6" ng-model="a.one" name=""/>
<input type="number" class="col-md-6" ng-model="a.two" name="" ng-disabled="cm" required="required"/>
<div class='input-group date' id='date'>
                          <input type='text' ng-model="a.three" name="toDate" class="form-control" style="height:30px;" ng-disabled="cm" />
                          <span class="input-group-addon">
                           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                          </span>
                        </div>
```

when I select one value from below input:

```
<select class="col-md-6 dropdown-height" ng-model="a.select" name="" ng-options="ms for ms in section" required="required"></select>
```

the option values inside the select input are coming from an api

```
scope.mapping = function () {
          ApiServices.getAllValues().then(
                function (response) {
                   scope.map= response.data;
                 });
             };
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Do on the inputs this: `<input  ng-disabled="a.select" />`. This evaluates to truthy if `a.select` is filled with a value

Comment: There will be only three-four vaIues and I need to disable them for only one specific value.

Comment: Then do `ng-disabled="a.select == 'theSpecificValue'"`

Comment: Thanks it worked @devqon

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input ng-disabled="a.select==='your_value'">
```

Do this for the three inputs.

Comment: There will be only three-four vaIues and I need to disable them for only one specific value.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do it.
1. apply `ng-disabled="a.select"` to the element you want to disable.
2. This is much better if you want to apply to more input fields.
Wrap your html inside fieldset and apply ng-disabled. Below is the working code

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.cm = true;
  $scope.enable= function() {
    $scope.cm = !$scope.cm;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<fieldset ng-disabled="cm">
<input type="text" class="col-md-6" ng-model="a.one" name=""/>
<input type="number" class="col-md-6" ng-model="a.two" name="" required="required"/>
<div class='input-group date' id='date'>
                          <input type='text' ng-model="a.three" name="toDate" class="form-control" style="height:30px;" />
                          <span class="input-group-addon">
                           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                          </span>
                        </div>
</fieldset>
  <button ng-click="enable()">enable fields</button>
  </div>
```